# Is there a way to pass elements to a vue component?

Tags: vue.js

when I need to pass some information between child and parent element I use props. But is there a way to pass elements to the component, for example like this

```
<MyComponent>
 <router-link to="/oneOfTheList">OneOfTheList</router-link>
</MyComponent>
```

Router-Link seems to do it somehow...
How can I specify where the elements will be placed in my component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called **slot**

ComponentA.vue

```
<div>
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

ComponentB.vue

```
<component-a>
    <span>test</span> // this part will be shown inside component A's slot tags
</component-a>
```

Here you [go](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)